# select picture by choosing date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a simple web page, where user can select a picture by choosing date in datepicker. The picture filenames consist date string. For example: img-2018-06-24.png. So far, I could get work this datepicker example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

//selecting the button and adding a click event
$("#alert").click(function() {
//alerting the value inside the textbox
var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
alert($.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date));
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Alert the value: <button id="alert">Alert!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

which popups the selected date after clicking on the button. Instead, I would like to put a picture according to selected date. So, I need to somehow pass the date to filename string and use it in :

`<img src= filename alt="myimage">`

But, so far no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does following code work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

//selecting the button and adding a click event
$("#alert").click(function() {
    //alerting the value inside the textbox
    var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
        if(date) {
            var imgSrc = 'img-' + $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date) + '.png';
            $('#show-image').show().attr('src', imgSrc);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<img src='' alt="myimage" id="show-image" style="display:none;">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<p>Alert the value: <button id="alert">Alert!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This how you can add src on image

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script> 
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); //selecting the button and adding a click event 
$("#alert").click(function() { //alerting the value inside the textbox
 var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker("getDate");

 alert($.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date));

var src= $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date);
$("#image").attr("src",src+".jpg").show();

});
 }); 
</script> </head> <body> 
<img id="img" src="" style="display:none;">
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> <p>Alert the value: <button id="alert">Alert!</button> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `src` attribute of `img` inside the click event like this -

```
$("img").attr("src",$.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date));
```

If you want to change the alt attribute as well, you can do it the same way -

```
$("img").attr("alt",$.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date));
```

See working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/267s1my9/5/)